# Confinement result for unit complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, summation

Inspired by this [problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1649062), and some computer simulations, I almost convinced myself of the following result. However, I am coming short on a proof.

**Result:** Let $n\geq 3$, and $2n+1$ complex numbers $z_{1},\ldots ,z_{2n+1}$ on the unit circle such that $\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} z_{k} =0$.

There exists $\mathscr{I} \subset \{ 1,\ldots, 2n+1 \}$, such that $|\mathscr{I}| = n$ and $$\left| \sum_{i \in \mathscr{I}} z_{i}\right| \leq \frac{n-1}{n}.$$

1. Is this result true?
2. Is it known?
3. If so, any proof?

Note: There are other confinement results for instance the [Polygonal Confinement Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062389/does-the-polygonal-confinement-theorem-hold-on-the-set-of-entire-functions).

Comment: What if $n=2$ and $z_1, \ldots, z_5$ are the fifth root of unity? I don't think that $|z_j+z_k| \le 1/2$ for any two of them.

Comment: If you define $C_n$ as the smallest possible value of $\left| \sum_{i \in \mathscr{I}} z_{i}\right| $ then I my guess would be that $C_n$ *decreases* with $n$.

Comment: @MartinR: maybe, but we already know that $C_n \leq 1$, so…

Comment: @MartinR I changed $n\geq 3$ instead of $n\geq 2$. I think $C_n$ increases with $n$.

Comment: Can you share your code for the computer simulation?

Comment: @MartinR Here is some code for $n=7$, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oP3Ej4MDd6ohWiLQiPa_wUQdjTfiRMHE?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=9$, $\xi$ be a nonreal cubic root of $1$ and $z_k=\xi^k$ for each $k\in\{1,\dots,9\}$.
It is easy to check that for each $\mathscr{I} \subset \{ 1,\ldots, 9 \}$ with $|\mathscr{I}| = 4$ we have $\left| \sum_{i \in \mathscr{I}} z_{i}\right|\ge 1.$

Comment: Thanks Alex, so the upper bound $\frac{n-1}{n}$ in the statement above is wrong. What about the upper bound 1 instead (which was from the initial problem linked above)?

Comment: @NathanPortland The solution idea proposed there looks OK.